# Trying to get vertical text to bottom align

Tags: html, webkit, css

The layout I'm trying to achieve is shown in this image:
[image]

The HTML below is one of many attempts which haven't worked.  The project this is for is targeting HTML5 in the latest browsers only, so there is no need for it to work in anything except the latest Chrome, Safari, Firefox and (with a following wind) IE9 beta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; width:600px; height: 600px">
        <span style="-webkit-transform:rotate(-

90deg);display:block;position:absolute;bottom:600px">My Vertical Text</span>
        <img src="http://www.gizmodo.com/assets/resources/2007/01/Bill-gates-mugshot.jpg"  

style="position:absolute;bottom:600px" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you might want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aNscn/3/

`bottom: 600px` is going to get you nowhere - that's just going to put the elements 600px away from the bottom of the user's screen. Instead, give the outer `div` a `position: relative` and let the two elements align to it's bottom with a suitably low `bottom` value. Also check out the `transform-origin` property to get the positioning of the `span` correct after rotation.

```
#outer {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width:600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

#text {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5px;
}

#img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that works.  Very impressive.  Just one thing though -- the left:30px on the image assumes the width of the text.  Is it not possible to make the image float to the right of the text automatically?

Comment: @Nestor Not really, not with this approach at least, though you can try using `em` units instead if that helps.

Comment: yes its been almost 11 years, but your solution is fantastic.  this works VERY well for multiple columns too.  thank you.